# Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "" in AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a laravel application that has been sending emails for Years now. Recently, emails have been failing to send. When I check the failed_jobs table, below is the error message:

```
Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "", with message "" in 
/apps/www/ccc.xxxx.com/public_html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php:383
```

Below are things I have attempted:

- composer dump-autoload
- php artisan config:cache
- php artisan config:clear
- php artisan queue:restart
- restarted supervisor
- Ensure username and password is correct in .env file
- I have connected to the mail box successfully and able to send email to anyone

Below is the .env config

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=g.blah@balh.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=Va#@2016
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=TLS
```

What can be the issue and how to fix this ?

Comment: Although you have mentioned that username and password are correct, I am not sure if it is. Also, could you change `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` to `STARTTLS` and wrap password to double quote. `MAIL_PASSWORD="Va#@2016"`  and `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=STARTTLS`

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105920/package-swiftmailer-swiftmailer-is-abandoned-you-should-avoid-using-it-use-sym#:~:text=Abandoned%20does%20not%20mean%20bad,the%20mail%20package%20for%20years.) comment

Comment: Hi @SarojShrestha, I have done as commented but no success. I have also checked that port 587 is open and it is open

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Swiftmailer abandoned but it's still working fine with PHP 7 versions, maybe your PHP has been upgraded by someone or server administrator. Please check your PHP version and look at this file in your Swiftmailer vendor and change it if necessary.

Replace 127.0.0.1 to gethostname() in `lib/dependency_maps/transport_deps.php`

Comment: Hi @Martin Amu, there is no 127.0.0.1 in transport_deps.php